# Error on JSon Serialization

Tags: c#

I'm currently experiecing an error message below when calling my webapi.

{"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"The 'ObjectContent`1' type failed to serialize the response body for content type 'application/json; charset=utf-8'

Below is my code

```
public User getUser(string userName)
    {
        UserDAO userDao = db.GetDAO<UserDAO>();

        var user = userDao.GetWhere(x => x.Username == userName).ToList();
        if (user.Count < 1)
        {
            //the user is not yet in the database. 
            return new User { UserId = -1 };
        }

        return user.FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Comment: How the User class and UserDAO class look like?

Comment: I guess there's some referenced field in your User Class that can not serialize. You can try to return a plain Object to avoid the error.